# Realtime RTMP streaming of user-uploaded files, as they upload

Tags: flash, audio, streaming, mp3, rtmp

I want users to be able to upload audio files to my server (say, over HTTP.. mechanism doesn't matter much), and then I'd like to assemble those files into a playlist and stream them out over a live RTMP stream to a Flash widget.

The catch is: I'd like to begin streaming the audio files before they completely finish uploading. For example, if a user uploads an hour-long mp3, I'd like it to be able to begin playing on the RTMP stream once, say, the first minute has been uploaded.

I'd like to support mp3 and AAC, and would hope to avoid re-encoding the files. Is is there a way to make this work with Wowza, Flash Media Server, or some other clever solution?

Thanks a lot for any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, with Wowza, is to manually parse the mp3 file into frames, and then dump them directly into a publisher stream. Here's an example of doing something similar:

http://www.wowzamedia.com/forums/showthread.php?t=7100

Other than that, Wowza does not support streaming partially uploaded files:

http://www.wowzamedia.com/forums/showthread.php?p=33908